# How to Increment a PHP Variable In a CRON

Tags: php, cron

I have a simpleXML file that is being generated from a rest api call and will be fed into a database on a scheduled basis via a cronjob.

The results returned from the API calls are limited to 10 per page and the problem I am having is updating the page number parameter for the call to get the next set of results

```
$page_number = 1;
$page = $page_number++;

$api_url = "example.com/rest/api?products=new&pageid=$page";
```

I'm not sure how to get the variable $page to increment on each cron, any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store in:

- File => See other answers. You need access to file-system for this(But I think you should have this or move along).
- [Redis](http://redis.io)(or [Memcached](http://memcached.org)) => http://redistogo.com offers free instance of Redis and predis very popular PHP library to connect to redis. This solution will (almost' always work and will be very fast. You only need `socket` for this.
- SQL => You should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to connect to SQL if your hosting provider offers this. Also I think it should offer this or you should move along.

Answer (score 1):

make new empty file in /tmp/file.txt

```
$page_number = file_get_contents("/tmp/file.txt");
if (!$page_number) $page_number = 1;
$page = $page_number + 1;
$f = fopen("/tmp/file.txt", "w+");
fwrite($f, $page);
fclose($f);

$api_url = "example.com/rest/api?products=new&pageid=$page";
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the number in a DB Or as a file with only the number as content would be the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fname = '/tmp/pager_counter'; // don't use tempnam function here!!!
$fp = fopen($fname, 'w+');
$page = (int)fread($fp, filesize($fname));
if (!$page) {
    $pgae=0;
}
$page++;
fwrite($fp, $page, strlen((string)$page));

$api_url = "example.com/rest/api?products=new&pageid=$page";
```

You could as easily use any another database or cache (`MySQL`, `memcache`, etc.)